# How to mock with NSubstitute in IntegrationTest

Tags: c#, xunit, nsubstitute

I have a ContainerFixture class that I use in my integration test which is as per below:

```
services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IWebHostEnvironment>(w =>
 w.EnvironmentName == "Development" &&
 w.ApplicationName == "Application.WebUI"));
```

In the above example, I am using Moq, but I want to use NSubstitute.

When I replace Mock.of with Substitute.For, I get the below error:

```
services.AddSingleton(Substitute.For<IWebHostEnvironment>(w =>
 w.EnvironmentName == "Development" &&
 w.ApplicationName == "Application.WebUI"));
```

> Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to the type 'object' because it is not of a delegate type.

How should we use Substitute for the above example?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but the question title is a bit vague. Maybe that one could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters of the `.For` are passed as constructor arguments in NSubstitute. That could be useful for substituting classes with virtual members.

[image]

See also [the code of `Substitute`](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/0daeb8586daecd0cc44a7acd85ec312d4fe2ce99/src/NSubstitute/Substitute.cs#L19)

```
public static T For<T>(params object[] constructorArguments)
```

The equivalent in NSubstitute for your example:

```
var env = Substitute.For<IWebHostEnvironment>();
env.EnvironmentName.Returns("Development");
env.ApplicationName.Returns("Application.WebUI");
services.AddSingleton(env);
```